# Using new variables inside Makefile loops

Tags: loops, variables, foreach, makefile

After messing about with foreach loops, eval, and various combinations of dollar signs, brackets, semicolons and whatnot, I finally ended up getting the result I wanted with a bunch of shell commands within a Makefile.

I have a directory structure:

> > . 
>  > ./Makefile 
>  > ./source
>   
>  > ./source/a 
>  > ./source/b 
>  > ./source/c

And a Makefile:

```
WORKDIR?=$(shell pwd)/builddir_$(SRCDIR)

all: copy_sources test_var

copy_sources:
    mkdir $(WORKDIR)
    mkdir $(WORKDIR)/logs
    @rsync -paqhC $(SRCDIR) $(WORKDIR)/

test_var:
    cd $(WORKDIR)
    for TESTDIR in $(wildcard $(WORKDIR)/$(SRCDIR)/*); do \
        cd $$TESTDIR ; \
        TESTNAME=`basename $$TESTDIR`; \
        touch file_$${TESTNAME}_out.txt; \
        echo "done $${TESTNAME}" > $(WORKDIR)/logs/$${TESTNAME}.log; \
        cd $(WORKDIR); \
    done
```

which I invoke with:

> make all SRCDIR=source

It seems a bit convoluted, so I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using Makefile syntax instead of passing it all to the shell. I particularly had difficulty with assigning the basename to a variable and then using that variable.

Comment: *What* are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a number of tests, and I want to run each. This is a generic Makefile, so it could be any number of tests, and the names could be anything. The only thing I know in advance is that the directory structure is:

tests/test_1, tests/test_2, tests/test_3, etc.

I want to enter each directory, run the test, and direct the output to a log file in a shared logs directory.